# Extract Table as Text Using Php

Tags: php, web-scraping, match

I'm looking for a simple method to get the first table of a webpage and put the whole thing into a string, that is all.

So I need to know how to use preg_match or similar to get the first instance of a table from a DOM object and get that whole thing into a string:

I have a class to download webpages as DOM but I cannot convert the html to a string as I need it..

```
$nodes = $this->bot->QuerySelector($this->download['DOM'], "//table[1][@class='tyebfghjftsdf-ccfkk']");
```

Please help

Comment: What didi you try and what is the desierd output ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use Tidy to convert page to valid XHTML, then read it using XML reader (not building DOM) and start echoing data when  tag is found and terminate on  tag. No regular expressions involved.